# Problem exporting a plot with an inset plot (weird resizing)

Tags: plotting, bugs, export, rasterize

I'm having issues in saving out a plot with another plot inset within it. Here is a basic example.

`theInsetPlot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}];`

`plotWithInset = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, PlotRange -> {{0, 6 Pi}, {-10, 30}}, Epilog ->{Inset[theInsetPlot, {7, 15}]}]`

This gives me a plot with an inset plot. If I right click the image and use "save graphics as.." to save out a .jpeg I get the following. Which matches the notebook output image.

[image: Plot when manually exporting as a jpeg (same for other formats)]

However, if I rasterise the image

`Rasterize[plotWithInset]`

or save out with the following code

`Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testPlotAuto.jpeg", plotWithInset]`

I get this image

[image: Plot when exporting with code and/or rasterizing]

As you can see, the inset graph is scaled weirdly. This is the same for all of the different output formats I have tried.

My actual example is are complicated, but this minimal example shows the problem.

I'm on: "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed as a bug by Wolfram Tech Support. The following are workarounds until it is fixed.

For Rasterising

`Rasterize@Framed[plotWithInset, FrameStyle -> None]`

For Exporting

`Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "testPlotAuto1.jpeg", Framed[plotWithInset]]`